# Extending an extension method? Or something?

Tags: c#, methods

Sorry I'm not very clear. It's sort of hard to explain what I'm looking to do. I'd like to make extension methods but have them segregated. So for example...

```
bool b = true;
char c = b.bool_ext.convert_to_YorN();
int i = b.bool_ext.convert_to_1or0();
```

Is something like that possible? Thanks!

Comment: @mellamokb I clearly stated it was an example. That being said, I surely hope your code isn't full of irrelevant comments...

Comment: You could do it like that: `b.bool_ext().convert_to_YorN()`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I think that might suit my needs. Could you provide an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them "segregated", then you'd have to either invent your own type:

```
public struct MyBool {
    public MyBool(bool value) : this() {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public bool Value { get; private set; }
}

public static MyBoolExtensions {
    public static char convert_to_YorN(this MyBool value) {
        return value.Value ? 'Y' : 'N';
    }
}

public static BooleanExtensions {
    public static MyBool bool_ext(this bool value) {
        return new MyBool(value);
    }
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
bool b = true;
char c = b.bool_ext().convert_to_YorN();
```

Or just use them as static methods:

```
public class MyBoolConverters {
    public static char convert_to_YorN(bool value) {
        return value.Value ? 'Y' : 'N';
    }
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
bool b = true;
char c = MyBoolConverters.convert_to_YorN(b);
```

But you cannot categorize them like you show.

Answer (score 5):

No that is not possible, The `bool_ext` would be a extension *property* of `bool`, and you can not currently do extension properties, only extension methods.